# How could we use regular expression in GNUmake

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am new to GNUmake and I need to check if a string **does not** ends with "FEATURE" in it.

```
 ifeq (<check_if_a_string_doesnot_end_with_"FEATURE">)
   ....Do someting
 endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`patsubst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-patsubst-1) to check if after removing everything that ends in `FEATURE`, you don't end up with the empty string:

```
ifneq ($(patsubst %FEATURE,,$(var)),)
```

So for a minimal Makefile like

```
.PHONY: checksuffix
checksuffix:
ifneq ($(patsubst %FEATURE,,$(var)),)
    @echo "$(var) does not end with FEATURE"
else
    @echo "$(var) does end with FEATURE"
endif
```

the behaviour would be

```
$ make checksuffix var=MYFEATURE
MYFEATURE does end with FEATURE
$ make checksuffix var=FEATUREABC
FEATUREABC does not end with FEATURE
```